# Knockout Conditional - How can I have something happen every "X" times?

Tags: knockout.js

I want something to be visible starting on iteration 1, 33, 65, 97, 129.  Is there an easy way to to this?  Something similar to below?

```
<div data-bind="visible: Counter == 1 || Counter == Counter + 32" class="thin-ad">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [mod/remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25)) for that:

```html
<div data-bind="visible: Counter % 32 == 1" class="thin-ad">
```

EG:

```js
var vm = {
  c: ko.observableArray([])
}

for (var x = 0; x < 150; x++)
  vm.c.push({
    Counter: x
  });

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: c">
  <div data-bind="visible: Counter % 32 == 1, text: Counter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent and very clean.  Thanks!